# if else statement not working jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Is there anything wrong with my code? My if else statement is not working.

```
<%
String pages = request.getParameter("page");
%>
<input type="hidden" id="page" value="<%=pages%>"/>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="index.jsp">PeachMangoPie</a>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li <%if(pages=="papoy"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=papoy">Papoy</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li <%if(pages=="chuckie"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=chuckie">Chuckie</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li <%if(pages=="dutchmill"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=dutchmill">Dutch Mill</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li <%if(pages=="icecream"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=icecream">Ice Cream</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li <%if(pages=="chicken"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=chicken">Chicken</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li <%if(pages=="straberrycake"){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=strawberrycake">Strawberry-Cake</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: *Is there anything wrong in my code?* yes, usage of scriptlets: [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the .equals method to test for string equality.
Try this instead:

```
<li <%if(pages.equals("papoy")){out.write("class='active' ");}%>><a href="index.jsp?page=papoy">Papoy</a></li>
```

Comment: You're welcome. However, as @Luiggi mentioned in the comment above you should avoid using scriplets anyhow.

Comment: Check my answer to provide a way better solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code: use `equals` to compare `String`s (as shown in [Harshal Pandya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914542/1065197)).

To really fix your code: stop using scriptlets as explained here: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). Rewrite all this using [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and JavaScript. I wrote a basic example on this to omit all that hard-to-maintain scriptlet and HTML code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var page = '<c:out value="${param.page}" />';
        var ulOptions = document.getElementById('ulOptions');
        var liItems = ulOptions.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for(var i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++) {
            var liItem = liItems[i];
            var a = liItem.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a !== undefined && a.innerText.toLowerCase() === page) {
                liItem.setAttribute("class", "brand");
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="page" value="${param.page}"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="index.jsp">PeachMangoPie</a>
        <%--
            provided id for ul HTML component in order to ease
            JavaScript onload function development
        --%>
        <ul id="ulOptions" class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=papoy">Papoy</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=chuckie">Chuckie</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=dutchmill">Dutch Mill</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=icecream">Ice Cream</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=chicken">Chicken</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="index.jsp?page=strawberrycake">Strawberry-Cake</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation of the provided code:

- `${param.page}` replaces `request.getParameter("page");`
- `window.onload = function() { ... };` defining a JavaScript function to execute after loading the page (more info: [onload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)).
- `<c:out>` will print text directly on the generated HTML. More info: [`<c:out>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm).
- `document.getElementById` returns an HTML element by its id (the function name explains this pretty straightforward).
- `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` that contains all the inner HTML elements with the corresponding tag name (the function name explains this pretty straightforward).
- `for(var i = 0; i < liItems.length; i++)` traverse all the `<li>` elements inside `ulOptions`.
- `liItem.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` as explained before, get the `<a>` element in position `0`.
- `a !== undefined && a.innerText.toLowerCase() === page` verifying that `a` exists (this for those `<li>` without the `<a>` element inside) and verifying the inner text against the `page` request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is better approach (without scriptlets):

```
<li <c:out value="${param.page=='papoy'?'class=active':''}"/>">
   <a href="index.jsp?page=papoy">Papoy</a>
</li>
```